# Multiple Blog Layouts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, themes, blogs

I want to create a wordpress blog template. Like other themes have I don't just want one layout for my blog index page (home.php). I want to have the option that the user can select between 2 columns, 3 columns, some custom layout etc.
I know I could achieve this with static pages. But for the blog index there should not be static pages. So can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking.

Do you want your users to be able to pick from different layouts? In that case, write the layouts in HTML(you can use a frontend framework like Bootstrap to help you), use PHP to detect the user's choice(storing it in a cookie, for instance, and setting the value of the cookie with a simple form and post), and echo only the layout you'd like.

If that's not what you're asking, please update your question with some examples.